# Select statement over multiple columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have an SQLite database with a table `help` with columns `i_id`, `issue`, `url`, `steps`, `kw1`, `kw2`, [...], `kw12`. `kw1` - `kw12` contain one word and can be null.

When I do:

```
sqlite> select issue,url,steps from help where kw1='adobe';
```

I get:

```
blank popup|blankpopup.html|S
missing pdfs|missingpdfs.html|S
printall not populating|printall.html|A
```

this is right. When I move to another keyword like 'ie' that is in multiple fields across `kw1` - `kw12`, how do I do a select statement where instead of searching just `kw1`, it searches `kw1` *through* to `kw12`?

I know what fields 'ie' is in. I have an Excel sheet of how the database is built but the people using the database don't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand right, you just need to use Or keyword and search thru all the kw-fields

```
sqlite> select issue,url,steps from help where kw1='ie' or kw2='ie' or kw3='ie' or kw4='ie' or kw5='ie' or kw6='ie' or kw7='ie' or kw8='ie' or kw9='ie' or kw10='ie' or kw11='ie' or kw12='ie';
```